# Odrered pairing functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have four arrays like this

```
var Broker = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var Currency = ['C', 'D', 'E'];
var Time = ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
var Mode = ['J', 'K', 'L'];
```

so all theses arrays are shown in multiple select separtely.so when user selects the multiple field from each multi select dropdown i like to list all the paring possiblities with selected items
example`if user choose A and B from Broker, C from currency, F,G from time and J from mode the paring possiblity should be stored in another separate array like this
    var paired = [{borker:A,currency:C,time:F, mode: J},{borker:A,currency:C,time:G, mode: J},{borker:A,currency:C,time:F, mode: J}, {borker:B,currency:C,time:F, mode: J},{borker:B,currency:C,time:G, mode: K},{borker:B,currency:C,time:F, mode: L}];`

I may missed the items in paried array but i need atleast one unique item from all the selected arrays.Its kind of set.So can you guys how can i obtain this kind of result.

Comment: `{borker:A,currency:C,time:F, mode: J}` is duplicated, `{borker:B,currency:C,time:F, mode: L}` was not selected. Apart of that, it's simply generating permutations.

Comment: yes so how can i do such permutations in javascript @zerkms

Comment: You have a keyword now, have you tried to make *any* research?

Answer (score 2):

This code creates an array called `permutations` which holds an object for every possible permutation of choices. The nested for-loops are the trick to permutations.

```
var Broker = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var Currency = ['C', 'D', 'E'];
var Time = ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
var Mode = ['J', 'K', 'L'];
var permutations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < Broker.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < Currency.length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < Time.length; k++) {
            for(var l = 0; l < Mode.length; l++) {
                permutations.push({
                        borker:Broker[i],
                        currency:Currency[j],
                        time:Time[k],
                        mode:Mode[l]
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well with a few brokers and a few currencies and other options it might work fine, but what will happen if there are thousands of brokers and all available currencies, plus a lot of other options?

Comment: @Rolice: permutations do exponentially increase, but this still looks to be the most performant method of iteration to determine the permutations. I would definitely question computing the permutations if there were that many options, but this does seem to answer the question.

Comment: @lyjackal, I think the answer is based on a comment of member, below the question. It is mathematically correct, and this way all permutations will be covered. But in the case of the user asked, I think he might need some quite simple mapping (even with static mapping data).